# How to overcome malformed html in html table in PHP website

Tags: php, html-table, html-email

I have html table which displays content from email. This email content can be from any email client (browser, outlook, thunderbird...). If this html is malformed it creates a mess in my html table.

For example: if the email content has any unclosed tags or malformed table in it, it is destroying the structure of my table where I am displaying this email content.

Could you please tell me is there any alternative to display this content without any disturbance to my main table......

Here is the screen shot:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/ilUA4b89]

Comment: Without you showing samples of said malformed html it's going to be hard getting any decent answer. A screenshot tells us nothing. That said: you could try to fix the html with libtidy.

Comment: sorry peehaa... for example: email content is like this
<div> this is sample text </div></td></tr><tr><td>this is another text</td></tr>.....this html content displays in my table column. in this content we have closed </td> right? because of this my main table alignment is lost

Comment: Do you really need the HTML content of simply the textcontent as stated by @hadyn?

Comment: really need html content but not disturb to main table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to load the HTML content form email. You can then extract the body context and repair the malformed HTML.

**Example:**

```
<?php

    //note that the div tag is not closed properly 
    $emailContent = '<html><head></head><body><div>bla<div><h1>hgjhjdfg</h1></body></html>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $new = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($emailContent);

    //extract the body
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

    foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
        $new->appendChild($new->importNode($child, true));
    }

    //dom document automatically tries to repair malformed HTML so when we use saveHTML().
    echo $new->saveHTML();

?>
```

**Output:**

```
<div>bla<div><h1>hgjhjdfg</h1></div></div>
```

As you can see the unclosed `<div>` tags are now closed. If you did this with the HTML from e-mail (or wherever you are getting it from) you could fix the html this way.

However DOMDocument does not do a very good job if it comes to repairing malformed HTML so the results can be unexpected, but at least your table is not affected.

**Alternatives**

You can also use ajax to load every piece of email content separately. The browsers dom does a better job if it comes to repairing malformed HTML.

**Other problems**

You must also filter the email content on javascript. If it contains javascript it can also malform your table or even the entire web page.

For example someone put this inside a email (jquery):
     
          $('body').hide();

Comment: really nice snippet. thank you. actually i am getting another problem when i use this. please let me know how to resolve. here i am directly closing </tr> 
eg:  $emailContent = '<html><head></head><body><div>bla<div></tr><h1>hgjhjdfg</h1></body></html>';

then i am getting issue like
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : tr in Entity,

Comment: thank you so much....i resolved the issue using libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

Comment: @muralikalpana Well alright, Seems you found out the rest yourself.  If my answer solved your problem consider to accept my answer please.

Answer (score -3):

Use an iframe or strip out the HTML in php and use plain text.

[w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>"></iframe>
```

Comment: If your going to downvote, put a reason. This could have been a suitable answer depending on the OP's requirements which were not that clearly stated.